# Why Mapstruct don't use Lombok's builder with generic type?

Tags: java, lombok, builder, mapstruct

I have a class that represents a paged response that looks like this (all annotations are from Lombok):

```
@Value
@Builder
@Jacksonized
@FieldNameConstants
public class PagedResponse<T> {

    List<T> content;
    int number;
    int totalPages;
    int size;
    int numberOfElements;
    long totalElements;

}
```

and a dto class:

```
@Value
@Builder
@Jacksonized
@FieldNameConstants
public class CommentResponse {

    UUID uuid;
    String value;

}
```

I'm using Mapstruct to generate the mapper to map my entity `Comment` to my dto class, here's the mapper interface:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING)
public interface CommentMapper {

    PagedResponse<CommentResponse> mapToCommentResponses(Page<Comment> comments);

    CommentResponse mapToCommentResponse(Comment comment);

}
```

While Mapstruct have no problems generating the code for simple entity-dto mapping, it struggle to generate to code for the method `PagedResponse<CommentResponse> mapToCommentResponses(Page<Comment> comments);`

The generated code for the mapper:

```
@Component
public class CommentMapperImpl implements CommentMapper {

    @Override
    public PagedResponse<CommentResponse> mapToCommentResponses(Page<Comment> comments) {
        if ( comments == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<CommentResponse> content = null;
        int number = 0;
        int totalPages = 0;
        int size = 0;
        int numberOfElements = 0;
        long totalElements = 0L;

        if ( comments.hasContent() ) {
            content = commentListToCommentResponseList( comments.getContent() );
        }
        number = comments.getNumber();
        totalPages = comments.getTotalPages();
        size = comments.getSize();
        numberOfElements = comments.getNumberOfElements();
        totalElements = comments.getTotalElements();

        // next line cause a compile error
        PagedResponse<CommentResponse> pagedResponse = new PagedResponse<CommentResponse>( content, number, totalPages, size, numberOfElements, totalElements );

        return pagedResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public CommentResponse mapToCommentResponse(Comment comment) {
        if ( comment == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CommentResponse.CommentResponseBuilder commentResponse = CommentResponse.builder();

        commentResponse.uuid( comment.getUuid() );
        commentResponse.value( comment.getValue() );

        return commentResponse.build();
    }

    protected List<CommentResponse> commentListToCommentResponseList(List<Comment> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<CommentResponse> list1 = new ArrayList<CommentResponse>( list.size() );
        for ( Comment comment: list ) {
            list1.add( mapToCommentResponse( comment ) );
        }

        return list1;
    }
}
```

Here Mapstruct tries to call the package-private constructor of `PagedResponse` instead of the builder which cause a compile error.

I would expect Mapstruct to call the builder like this:

```
PagedResponse.PagedResponseBuilder builder = PagedResponse.<CommentResponse>builder()
```

or like this

```
PagedResponse.PagedResponseBuilder builder = PagedResponse.builder();
```

Is it even possible ? And how to achieve this ?

Edit:

The code of my entity `Comment`:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldNameConstants
public class Comment implements Persistable<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private UUID uuid;

    @Version
    private Integer version;
    
    private String value;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return Objects.isNull(id);
    }

    @PrePersist
    private void generateUuid() {
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

}
```

The class `Page` is from `org.springframework.data.domain.Page`

Comment: Do you have `lombok-mapstruct-binding` in your list of annotation processors?

Comment: Yes I have it, version 0.2.0

Comment: We need the whole code to reproduce your problem. In your description, the sources for `Comment` and `Page` are missing.

Comment: That looks like a mapstruct bug to me.

Comment: I will report this issue